# onClick notification pass data to fragment using bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've implemented a notification using AsyncTask and what I want to do is for the notification to pass data when clicked. Whenever I click on the notification I should proceed to a fragment which will get the data being passed. I'm using `Bundle` for the data to be passed on my Fragment Class. 
How to pass the bundle data to the Fragment

I tried using just the Intent and removing the Bundle but it doesn't do anything

```
new notifyThis(this, "2", "Title", "Description", "http://imgur.com/gallery/WBTdB").execute();
```

Notification asyncTask

```
public class notifyThis extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        private Context mContext;
        private String itemId, title, description, imageLink;
        Notification notification;
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        DetailsFragment detailsFragment;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        Bundle bundle;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        Intent intent;
        Resources res;

        public notifyThis(Context context, String itemId, String title, String description, String imageLink) {
            super();
            this.mContext = context;
            this.itemId = itemId;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.imageLink = imageLink;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

            InputStream in;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(this.imageLink);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                in = connection.getInputStream();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap imageResult) {
            super.onPostExecute(imageResult);

            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            final int idItem= Integer.valueOf(itemId);

            intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsFragment.class);

            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("id", idItem);

            detailsFragment= new DetailsFragment();
            detailsFragment.setTitle(title);
            detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, detailsFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack("details");
            transaction.commit();

            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            res = mContext.getResources();
            int height = (int) res.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height);
            int width = (int) res.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width);
            imageResult = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, width, height, false);

            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setLargeIcon(imageResult)
                    .setSubText(description)
                    .build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        }
}
```

This is how I the get data being passed - `DetailsFragment.class`

```
  if (save != null) {
    setTitle(save.getString("title"));
  }

  if (itemId != this.getArguments().getInt("id")) {
    itemId = this.getArguments().getInt("id");
    /do something here
  }
```

Comment: What exactly does "It doesn't seem to work this way." mean? Also I noticed you're getting a PendingIntent for an Activity, but you're passing and Intent that is not an Activity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you would need to use an Activity to launch from the notification. The activity would house the fragment you want to display. Have a static initializer in your fragment which will take the necessary parameters you want to pass to the fragment.

```
    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     * @return
     */
    public static ProductFragment newInstance(String category) {
        ProductFragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_CATEGORY, category);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Add the fragment instance returned from this method in your activity (standard fragment add using fragment manager). You can get the arguments from the fragment in `onCreate` like this -

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mCategory = getArguments().getString(ARG_CATEGORY);
        }
    }
```

Hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an Activity in pending intent and this activity should have your frame_container inside your activity on create you can check data and set fragment from there, because in this way fragment is nowhere related with your notification action.

Answer (score 0):

Add data to bundle and create a pending intent. add this to your notification manager

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_KEY,bundle);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(result)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```